# Resolve type projection in scala macro

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, type-projection

Consider the following traits:

```
sealed trait Test

//Test's branches

trait Base {
    type Action = Test
}
```

Now I need to get a `ClassSymbol` of `Test` referring to it as `Base#Action`.

Here is my attempt:

```
def macroImpl[B <: Base: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val baseType = weakTypeOf[B].typeSymbol.asType
    val actionType = c.typecheck(tq"$baseType#Action", mode = c.TYPEMode)
    println(tq"$actionType") //prints pack.age.Base#Action
    println(tq"$actionType".symbol) //prints type Action
    println(tq"$actionType".symbol.asClass) //raises scala.ScalaReflectionException: type Action is not a class

}
```

In my case `Base#Action = Test` which is definitely a class.

Is there a way to refer to its `ClassSymbol` from the macro implementation via type projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try firstly take the type of a tree

```
tq"$actionType".tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
```

---

I guess `val baseType = weakTypeOf[B]` will be shorter than `val baseType = weakTypeOf[B].typeSymbol.asType`. It's not clear why to go from type to symbol and then back to type.

> couldn't you please give a bit of explanation? It's not really obvious

The symbol of type member `Action` of trait `Base` and the symbol of trait `Test` are different. The type member `Action` is a type alias for `Test` but definitions of trait `Test` and type `Action` are different (symbols represent definitions).

The type member `Action` is not a class (trait) itself, it's a type. It's an alias for the type of a class (trait), but not a class itself.

Equal types can have different symbols.

I thought that we need to dealias in `tq"$actionType".tpe.dealias` (transforming the type `Base#Action` into `Test`) but it turns out that here dealiasing is aggressive and automatical so `tq"$actionType".tpe` is enough (the type `Test` already). Its symbol `tq"$actionType".tpe.typeSymbol` is the symbol of class (trait) `Test` and we can check that it's a `ClassSymbol` (and cast to it) with `.asClass`.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks much. But couldn't you please give a bit of explanation? It's not really obvious...

Comment: @SomeName I added some explanation.